# Iterate over data to flag IDs that have N consectutive hours

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Provided with the following data, I am trying to return deviceids that have N consecutive hours. The data is for a reading that is above 50% of it's average. I am trying to return any ID that has at least 4 consecutive hours in the list.(the hours is the key) I know it's possible to do it for 3 hours since we could use lag, is there a better way to do it for N hours? For example, if N is 3, 91428 would be included since 16/17/18 hours are consecutive.

```
deviceid  readdate
91428   2018-08-27 18:04:42
91428   2018-08-27 17:04:42
91428   2018-08-27 16:04:42
91428   2018-08-27 12:04:42
91428   2018-08-27 11:04:42
91428   2018-08-26 20:04:42
91428   2018-08-26 17:04:40
91428   2018-08-26 16:04:40
91428   2018-08-26 15:04:40
91428   2018-08-26 12:04:40
91489   2018-08-26 06:00:49
91493   2018-08-27 06:58:44
91511   2018-08-27 12:57:01
91511   2018-08-27 10:57:01
91511   2018-08-27 09:57:01
91511   2018-08-26 23:57:01
91511   2018-08-26 22:57:01
91511   2018-08-26 20:57:01
91511   2018-08-26 13:56:59
91511   2018-08-26 12:56:59
91511   2018-08-26 10:56:59
91547   2018-08-26 16:59:07
91547   2018-08-26 15:59:07
91547   2018-08-26 14:59:07
91547   2018-08-26 11:59:07
91547   2018-08-26 04:59:07
91582   2018-08-27 12:01:45
91582   2018-08-26 19:01:45
91582   2018-08-26 17:01:45
91582   2018-08-26 15:01:41
91582   2018-08-26 04:01:41
91657   2018-08-27 12:58:57
91657   2018-08-27 11:58:57
91657   2018-08-27 02:58:57
91657   2018-08-26 23:58:57
91657   2018-08-26 17:58:57
```

I am assuming there might be a way using count(*) ? I did a template but it started to get very complex so I am overthinking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a variation of a gap-and-islands problem.  On way to solve this is by using `lag()` to find where the islands start, then a cumulative sum to define each group.

```
select device_id, min(readdate), max(readdate)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_rd < readdate - interval '1 hour' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by device_id order by readdate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(readdate) over (partition by device_id order by readdate) as prev_rd
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by readdate, grp
having max(readdate) > min(readdate) + <n> * interval '1 hour';
```

Comment: I like your approach! If I wrap the results above to get the devices and their readings and then pass it along to this logic, would it be something like this?

Comment: excessivemeters as (
           select deviceid, min(readdate), max(readdate)
           from (select t.*, sum(case when prev_rd < readdate - interval '1 hour' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by device_id order by readdate) as grp
           from (
                select t.*, lag(readdate) over (partition by device_id order by readdate) as prev_rd
                from metersWithExcess) t
                ) t
group by readdate, grp
having max(readdate) > min(readdate) + 3 * interval '1 hour';
           ) 
                select deviceid
                from excessivemeters

Comment: Where metersWithExcess is a with as clause that would return the list above

Comment: @sql-noob . . . You can wrap this into a CTE.  You'll want to name the minimum and maximum read date columns.

Comment: Seem to get an error when doing that. Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause

Comment: @sql-noob . . . That is a Redshift thing.  You need to add `row between unbounded preceding and current row` after the `order by` clause in the `sum()`.

Comment: Seems that I need to include readdate in the first FROM clause. Doing so seems to not return any results back

Comment: select  []   from (  select deviceid, readdate, sum(case when prev_rd < readdate - interval '1 hour' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by deviceid order by readdate rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as grp
                   from (
                        select deviceid, readdate, lag(readdate) over (partition by deviceid order by readdate) as prev_rd
                    from metersWithExcess
                    order by readdate)
                ) tt
                group by deviceid, readdate, grp
                having mx > mn + 1 * interval '1 hour'
           )

Comment: Actually it worked... The problem with the query is that it's not finding the max island size. It's summing up all the island sizes

Comment: ideally it should only give us what the max island is and exclude any sizes of smaller islands